# Why my Httppost is not working when I turn off the screen?

Tags: android, post, background

I have one application in Android and I have two threads. One thread is checking the coordinates every 10 seconds and the other thread is sending this coordinates to my Server with Httppost.
When the screen is turn on the application works also when the application is in background.
But, when I turn off the screen the thread that checks the coordinates works but the thread that sends the Httppost does not work until I turn on the screen. Why?

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("MY_URL");
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        jsonArray = getJSONArray();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("msg", String.valueOf(jsonArray)));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        Thread.sleep(myService.getIntervalCoordinates() * 1000);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Comment: Are you using service? And in which device are you testing? 
Using service in background is restricted from nougat version.  

Would you please upload your code?

Comment: @Al-Amin But I don't understand why one of my threads is working and the other one does not working. The thread that sends the post resets the array after the run is executed. And the thread that checks the coordinates increase the jsonarray with the current coordinates.

Comment: Can you please upload your code? This might happen for various reasons.

Comment: So you're using service to get coordinates `myService`. I said previously that Using service is restricted upper versions of Android. 

You may try with `Workmanager` for your background tasks.

Comment: You need a [`WakeLock`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock) and possibly a [Foreground Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services).